# How to find out what the previous fragment was using the navigation

Tags: android-studio, android-fragments, navigation, uinavigationcontroller, fragment

the previous fragment in navigation control 
I need to know, which fragment is my previous fragment when 3 fragments navigates to a fragment.

Comment: You can pass an unique parameter like the fragment name while navigating to that fragment from your 3 fragments. See how to pass data [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-pass-data)